# capture follow subscription on facebook on follow button click

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook follow button. how can i capture that whether user successfully followed page or not in jquery or javascript?

below are my iframe code

```
<iframe id="facebookIf" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/follow.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fzuck&width=78&height=65&layout=button&size=large&show_faces=true&appId" width="78" height="65" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: That is not possible at all.

Comment: Why would you need to know?

Comment: @WizKid i want to show some message on my website when user successfully followed my page

Comment: They user already know that they followed your page